# Getting zero coverage on sonarQube after publishing sonar report via ci-pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am working on a maven project and want to setup sonar in ci-pipeline.
Below is my sonar setup script in gitlab-ci.yml.

```
before_script:
  - |
    run_mvn() {
      mvn -B \
       -s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml \
       -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository \
       -DfailIfNoTests=false \
       "$@"
    }

    run_sonar() {
      run_mvn \
        -Dsonar.projectKey=UI-Service \
        -Dsonar.host.url=xxx \
        -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN} \
        -Dsonar.sources=src/main \
        -Dsonar.tests=src/test \
        -Dsonar.java.binaries=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/target/*.classes \
        sonar:sonar
    }
```

And the sonar stage looks like below:

```
sonar:
  stage: analyse
  image: registry.git.xyyyy.com/containers/builder-images/maven/jdk-11:3.6.0
  when: manual
  script:
    - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - run_sonar
```

Now after the sonar stage runs in pipeline, I am getting these logs:

```
[INFO] 
70[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar (default-cli) @ ui-service ---
71[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
72[INFO] SonarQube version: 8.9.0
73[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
74[INFO] Load global settings
75[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=879ms
76[INFO] Server id: xxx
77[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
78[INFO] Load/download plugins
79[INFO] Load plugins index
80[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=199ms
81[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=28761ms
82[INFO] Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
83[INFO] JavaScript/TypeScript frontend is enabled
84[INFO] Process project properties
85[INFO] Process project properties (done) | time=12ms
86[INFO] Execute project builders
87[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=2ms
88[INFO] Project key: UI-Service
89[INFO] Base dir: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service
90[INFO] Working dir: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar
91[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'UI-Service'
92[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'UI-Service' (done) | time=160ms
93[INFO] Load project branches
94[INFO] Load project branches (done) | time=153ms
95[INFO] Load project pull requests
96[INFO] Load project pull requests (done) | time=147ms
97[INFO] Load branch configuration
98[INFO] Detected branch/PR in 'GitLab'
99[INFO] Auto-configuring branch 'feature/1242'
100[INFO] Load branch configuration (done) | time=3ms
101[INFO] Auto-configuring with CI 'Gitlab CI'
102[INFO] Load quality profiles
103[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=220ms
104[INFO] Auto-configuring with CI 'Gitlab CI'
105[INFO] Load active rules
106[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=5545ms
107[INFO] Branch name: feature/1242
108[INFO] Indexing files...
109[INFO] Project configuration:
110[INFO] 54 files indexed
111[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
112[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
113[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module ui-service
114[INFO] JavaScript/TypeScript frontend is enabled
115[INFO] Load metrics repository
116[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=156ms
117[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
118[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 11
119[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
120[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=7ms
121[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
122[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=2ms
123[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
124[INFO] 47 source files to be analyzed
125[INFO] Load project repositories
126[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=164ms
127[INFO] 47/47 source files have been analyzed
128[WARNING] Unresolved imports/types have been detected during analysis. Enable DEBUG mode to see them.
129[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=7835ms
130[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
131[INFO] 6 source files to be analyzed
132[INFO] 6/6 source files have been analyzed
133[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=587ms
134[INFO] Java Generated Files AST scan
135[INFO] 0 source files to be analyzed
136[INFO] 0/0 source files have been analyzed
137[INFO] Java Generated Files AST scan (done) | time=1ms
138[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=8839ms
139[INFO] Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily]
140[INFO] No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
141[INFO] Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1ms
142[INFO] Sensor PmdSensor [pmd]
143[INFO] Sensor PmdSensor [pmd] (done) | time=0ms
144[INFO] Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp]
145[INFO] Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
146[INFO] Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
147[INFO] Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
148[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
149[INFO] parsing [/builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/surefire-reports]
150[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=127ms
151[INFO] Sensor Removed properties sensor [java]
152[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is no longer supported. Use JaCoCo's xml report and sonar-jacoco plugin.
153[INFO] Sensor Removed properties sensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
154[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
155[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=2ms
156[INFO] Sensor HTML [web]
157[INFO] Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=3ms
158[INFO] Sensor CheckstyleSensor [checkstyle]
159[INFO] Checkstyle output report: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/checkstyle-result.xml
160[INFO] Checkstyle configuration: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
161[INFO] Checkstyle charset: UTF-8
162[INFO] Sensor CheckstyleSensor [checkstyle] (done) | time=888ms
163[INFO] Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]
164[INFO] Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=1ms
165[INFO] Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
166[INFO] Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=1ms
167[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
168[INFO] 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
169[INFO] No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
170[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=4ms
171[INFO] Sensor ThymeLeaf template sensor [securityjavafrontend]
172[INFO] Sensor ThymeLeaf template sensor [securityjavafrontend] (done) | time=1ms
173[INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs]
174[INFO] Loading findbugs plugin: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/findbugs/findsecbugs-plugin.jar
175[INFO] Findbugs output report: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
176The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
177  makeConcatWithConstants
178  requestResponse
179  requestStream
180  apply
181  test
182  accept
183  compare
184  run
185[INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs] (done) | time=8138ms
186[INFO] Sensor JavaSecuritySensor [security]
187[INFO] Reading type hierarchy from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/java
188[INFO] Read 172 type definitions
189[INFO] Reading UCFGs from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/java
190[INFO] 09:43:23.968449 Building Runtime Type propagation graph
191[INFO] 09:43:23.994976 Running Tarjan on 1615 nodes
192[INFO] 09:43:24.000773 Tarjan found 1608 components
193[INFO] 09:43:24.007245 Variable type analysis: done
194[INFO] 09:43:24.009926 Building Runtime Type propagation graph
195[INFO] 09:43:24.021118 Running Tarjan on 1615 nodes
196[INFO] 09:43:24.022848 Tarjan found 1608 components
197[INFO] 09:43:24.026061 Variable type analysis: done
198[INFO] Analyzing 173 ucfgs to detect vulnerabilities.
199[INFO] All rules entrypoints : 0 Retained UCFGs : 0
200[INFO] rule: S5131, entrypoints: 0
201[INFO] rule: S5131 done
202[INFO] rule: S3649, entrypoints: 0
203[INFO] rule: S3649 done
204[INFO] rule: S2076, entrypoints: 0
205[INFO] rule: S2076 done
206[INFO] rule: S2091, entrypoints: 0
207[INFO] rule: S2091 done
208[INFO] rule: S2078, entrypoints: 0
209[INFO] rule: S2078 done
210[INFO] rule: S2631, entrypoints: 0
211[INFO] rule: S2631 done
212[INFO] rule: S5135, entrypoints: 0
213[INFO] rule: S5135 done
214[INFO] rule: S2083, entrypoints: 0
215[INFO] rule: S2083 done
216[INFO] rule: S5167, entrypoints: 0
217[INFO] rule: S5167 done
218[INFO] rule: S5144, entrypoints: 0
219[INFO] rule: S5144 done
220[INFO] rule: S5145, entrypoints: 0
221[INFO] rule: S5145 done
222[INFO] rule: S5146, entrypoints: 0
223[INFO] rule: S5146 done
224[INFO] rule: S5334, entrypoints: 0
225[INFO] rule: S5334 done
226[INFO] rule: S6096, entrypoints: 0
227[INFO] rule: S6096 done
228[INFO] Sensor JavaSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1507ms
229[INFO] Sensor CSharpSecuritySensor [security]
230[INFO] Reading type hierarchy from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/ucfg_cs2
231[INFO] Read 0 type definitions
232[INFO] Reading UCFGs from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/ucfg_cs2
233[INFO] No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
234[INFO] Sensor CSharpSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1ms
235[INFO] Sensor PhpSecuritySensor [security]
236[INFO] Reading type hierarchy from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/php
237[INFO] Read 0 type definitions
238[INFO] Reading UCFGs from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/php
239[INFO] No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
240[INFO] Sensor PhpSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1ms
241[INFO] Sensor PythonSecuritySensor [security]
242[INFO] Reading type hierarchy from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/python
243[INFO] Read 0 type definitions
244[INFO] Reading UCFGs from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/python
245[INFO] No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
246[INFO] Sensor PythonSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1ms
247[INFO] Sensor JsSecuritySensor [security]
248[INFO] Reading type hierarchy from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/js
249[INFO] Read 0 type definitions
250[INFO] Reading UCFGs from: /builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/target/sonar/ucfg2/js
251[INFO] No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
252[INFO] Sensor JsSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1ms
253[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on project
254[INFO] Sensor Dependency-Check [dependencycheck]
255[INFO] Process Dependency-Check report
256[INFO] Using JSON-Reportparser
257[INFO] Dependency-Check JSON report does not exists. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath:/builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.json
258[INFO] JSON-Analysis skipped/aborted due to missing report file
259[INFO] Using XML-Reportparser
260[INFO] Dependency-Check XML report does not exists. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.xmlReportPath:/builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.xml
261[INFO] XML-Analysis skipped/aborted due to missing report file
262[INFO] Dependency-Check HTML report does not exists. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath:/builds/FJ8nuibS/0/xxx/ui-service/${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.html
263[INFO] HTML-Dependency-Check report does not exist.
264[INFO] Process Dependency-Check report (done) | time=5ms
265[INFO] Sensor Dependency-Check [dependencycheck] (done) | time=5ms
266[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
267[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=56ms
268[INFO] Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer
269[INFO] Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=87ms
270[INFO] SCM Publisher SCM provider for this project is: git
271[INFO] SCM Publisher 50 source files to be analyzed
272[INFO] SCM Publisher 50/50 source files have been analyzed (done) | time=490ms
273[INFO] CPD Executor 9 files had no CPD blocks
274[INFO] CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 38 files
275[INFO] CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=14ms
276[INFO] Load New Code definition
277[INFO] Load New Code definition (done) | time=973ms
278[INFO] Analysis report generated in 1101ms, dir size=602 KB
279[INFO] Analysis report compressed in 169ms, zip size=220 KB
280[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 1642ms
```

And the link to report is then generated, but when I open sonarQube to see the coverage, its 0%, even though all the main files and test files can be seen in code section.

Looking at the logs, I can't get the issue why the coverage is not being generated on sonarQube.

Anyone having a good experience with ci-pipeline or sonar setup on pipeline please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the state I discern from your comments, I'd say there are two common sticking points you have to deal with.

First, concerning "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", you now should be using "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", and it should have a value like "${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml".

Second, you will have to ensure that the Surefire and Jacoco maven plugins are properly working together.  Jacoco computes arguments that have to go into the Surefire command line.  This can be facilitated by the following two blocks:

This is part of the Surefire plugin configuration:

```
<execution>
  <id>pre-unit-test</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

This is in the jacoco plugin configuration block:

```
<argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yous need the compiled class to do sonar analysis. So in your `run_sonar()` add `package` to maven command.

```
run_sonar() {
      run_mvn \
        -Dsonar.projectKey=UI-Service \
        -Dsonar.host.url=xxx \
        -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN} \
        -Dsonar.sources=src/main \
        -Dsonar.tests=src/test \
        package \
        sonar:sonar
}
```

Comment: This issue is now not coming, what I did was instead of running "build" and "sonar" stages in parallel, I changed them the way that they should run one after another. This will help sonar stage to access the compiled libraries formed after build stage.

Comment: A new issue is coming now after the report is published, I am updating the question regarding that.

Comment: Are you using jacoco?

Comment: Yeah I am using jacoco reports, let me share the build command. ```build:
  stage: build
  image: registry.git.xxyy.com/containers/builder-images/maven/jdk-11:3.6.0
  script:
    - run_mvn clean install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/ ```

Comment: In the sonarqube ui, getting this warning ```Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is no longer supported. Use JaCoCo's xml report and sonar-jacoco plugin```